# The Maharalnach

Tags: jewish-books, authorship

The Mishneh Lemelech on Hilchot Chametz Umatzah 1:7 (in the Frankel edition, 2nd line from top of second column) quotes a certain Maharalnach and his 18th responsa. I took this as a typo for the Maharalbach - and sure enough - at the 18th responsa of the Maharalbach was the relevant topic (חצי שעור). However, the Sefer Halikutim **also** records it as the Maharal**nach**. 
 This became a bit more complicated when I looked up a different version and saw that it said the 51st responsa. I'm really confused, as I cannot find reference to this Maharalnach in the "גדולי ישראל" book, which is a comprehensive list of all Rabbonim up until the modern era.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MaharalNach and MaharalBach are the same person. Rabbi Levi ibn Chaviv. If you state the Arabic version of 'son of' it's ibn, abbreviated as a single Nun, hence the N'Ch(aviv). If you write the Hebrew version of 'son of' it's ben, hence the B'Ch(aviv).

Here's his wiki entry http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi_ibn_Habib

Comment: Facepalm. I still have to figure out the 18 vs 51 issue, though.

Comment: @shman613 we all get one once in a while:) we'll have to see about the 18 51 thing...